# System.Timers.Timer Stop losing values?

Tags: c#

I am making a console application that will later be a Windows service application through Topshelf.

I am struggling with timers, I setup a timer with autoreset of 20 seconds. When I start the timer it works. And when I stop it it stops.

Now to the problem, I want to keep the value when stopping it.

I need an event handler as Timer offers. But I also need to have a way that remembers the time as Stopwatch does. Which should I choose? I have access to SQL server and save it.

Lets say I let it run for 10 seconds since autoreset is true, when I stop it. And then wait, and then start the timer again.

In my opinion, the next time I start the timer it should only run for 10 seconds. So the total time that fires up the event is 20 second and not 30.

Is there any way to "save" elapsed time on it?

```
public class MySampleClient
{
    System.Timers.Timer BatchTimer;

    public MySampleClient()
    {
       BatchTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(BatchSampleTimer) { AutoReset = true };
    }

    public async Task startSession()
    {
        BatchTimer.Elapsed += BatchTimerVoid;
    }

    public void BatchIDTrigger(BatchTagDataModel btdm)
    {
        string btdmValue = btdm.Value.ToLower();

        if (batchNumberTimerControllerList.Contains(btdm.DisplayName))
        {
            if (btdmValue == "true")
            {
                BatchTimer.Start();
            }
            else 
            {
                BatchTimer.Stop();
            } 
        }
    }

    public void BatchTimerVoid(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs   e)
    {
        // Something happens here every 20 seconds.
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the relevant code, please?

Comment: " need an event handler as Timer offers and therefor I'm not trying Stopwatch because I dont know how to." - let me say that I do not understand tthis. TOTALLY confusing english. No idea what you mean.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko , yeah i will. Thanks!

TomTom, sorry will clarify it.

Comment: @TomTom better? Sorry for my poor english. I hope this is enough to get the help I need.

Comment: It looks answerable now.

Comment: I guess you don't need high accuracy, then consider to use 1 sec timer, where inside you just increment a value of property and once it hits 19 - reset it to zero and do "something". This way you can store/restore value of property either each time it's changed or upon exit/start (not sure with services).

Comment: I am trying to implement it with a counter. It needs to be pretty accurate, is this not accurate?

My plan is to use 1 second timer and count up second. Whenever I stop the timer I save the seconds to the sql.

Comment: "In my oppinion, the next time i start the timer it should only run for 10 seconds" - yeah, and your opinion is based on which part of the documentation? Starting resets the timer. There is no  passed time memory. It is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation. So, what do you base your opinion on?

Comment: They are honestly not based on anything specific, after what i have read it made sense but yeah, there are absolutely no documents. It is more a "aha" moment after trying it out than anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a simple extension to a `System.Timers.Timer` to provide you with a `Pause()` method. It uses a backing `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` to modify the `Timer.Interval` according to the elapsed period before the pause.

```
public class ExtendedTimer: System.Timers.Timer
{
    public long MillisecondsElapsed { get { return backingStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds; } }
    public new double Interval { get; private set; }

    private Stopwatch backingStopwatch;

    public ExtendedTimer(double interval) : base(interval)
    { 
        Interval = interval;
        backingStopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        base.Elapsed += ExtendedTimer_Elapsed;
    }

    private void ExtendedTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.Interval = this.Interval;
        backingStopwatch.Restart();
    }

    public new void Start()
    {
        base.Interval = this.Interval - backingStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        base.Start();
        backingStopwatch.Start();
    }

    public new void Stop()
    {
        base.Stop();
        backingStopwatch.Reset();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        base.Stop();
        backingStopwatch.Stop();
    }
}
```

Since there is now some overhead introduced, I cannot speak to how accurately it will maintain precision timings compared to the original implementation.

Comment: thanks alot, this was somehow what I wanted to see. I will think about implementing this or going with the sql way. 

Im thinking sql way will be better since i need to be pretty accurate.

Comment: No problem, test a little with diligence as I myself haven’t used it before. This will still be more than “pretty accurate”, I’d be surprised if more than a few milliseconds is lost to the management :)

Comment: Hm, I went with my way as explained above. Appreciate the help from you.

I only create a timer once with autoreset of 1000ms, but it seems to rerun at 2 seconds according to values. So when I halfen it, it works as intended. 

I am not running on multiple threads since the process memory is stable ( I assume thats how I see it). Is it just a coincidence that it runs every 2 second? It feels like it.

Comment: Never mind, i sent to many SQL querries so they slowed down the program. It sent once a second for testing purposes. In real life i will send them each 60 second. Thanks anyway.